# Docker can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, laradock

Hi i am new to laradock so i have couple of questions.

First i can't connect to my sql

What i did

```
sudo docker-compose up -d apache2 mysql workspace
```

got this when i do sudo docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
030fc427ea1e        laradock_apache2     "/opt/docker/bin/ent…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   laradock_apache2_1
e07c40bdd466        laradock_php-fpm     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          9000/tcp                                   laradock_php-fpm_1
838c5d1b18fc        laradock_workspace   "/sbin/my_init"          2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp                       laradock_workspace_1
af7e34cd464e        docker:dind          "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          2375/tcp                                   laradock_docker-in-docker_1
069f3cb37be3        laradock_mysql       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

that telling me that mysql is started

I have this in laradoc env file

```
MYSQL_VERSION=latest
MYSQL_DATABASE=default
MYSQL_USER=default
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

so i can't connect to mysql with Sequel Pro typing user "default"  password "secret" using as host http://127.0.0.1

My second question would be, 
should i access

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash
```

then start

```
php artisan serve
```

and

```
npm hot run
```

because i am using react in combination with laravel. Any help is appreciated. Tnx!

Comment: Pls do not ask multiple questions in a single post because it makes answering, accepting an answer and searching a lot more difficult.

Comment: yeah ok can you answer on one of them

Comment: No, you shouldn’t use `docker-compose exec ...` to start your containers’ primary services; put a default CMD in their Dockerfiles that launches the single thing they do as foreground processes.

Comment: so i have to put npm hot run into dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So issue was i actual laradock

Replace this line in env file

```
MYSQL_VERSION=LASTEST
```

WITH

```
MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
```